# IvoryCKEditorBundle: how to customize toolbar items?

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, ckeditor, bundle

I need to customize the items of the toolbar of the Symfony bundle IvoryCKEditorBundle.

I know that the toolbar can be customized by adding items to it in [this way](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/IvoryCKEditorBundle/usage/toolbar.html), but how can I edit an item itself or create a custom item?

The CKEditor documentation explains it [here](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_howtos_dialog_windows), but I'm not sure how to do the same using the Symfony IvoryCKEditor bundle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One elegant way could be by first [creating a CKEditor plugin](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/plugin_sdk_intro), and then [loading the plugin into the IvoryCKEditorBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/IvoryCKEditorBundle/usage/plugin.html):

```
# app/config/config.yml
ivory_ck_editor:
    default_config: my_config
    configs:
        my_config:
            extraPlugins: "mycustomplugin"
    plugins:
        mycustomplugin:
            path:     "/bundles/mybundle/mycustomplugin/"
            filename: "plugin.js"
```

the plugin folder (in my example `mycustomplugin`) should be placed under the `Resources/public` folder of the bundle source (e.g. `src/MyBundleName/Resources/pubic`).

Edit: also, be aware that if you need to install more than one plugin, the extraPlugins list should be separated by comma **without space**, like:

```
extraPlugins: "mycustomplugin1,mycustomplugin2,mycustomplugin3"
```